# ggplot: defining sexond axis changes format of first axis

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, axis, axis-labels

I make a plot using `ggplot2` with dates like this:

```
df <- data.frame(date= sample(seq(from=as.Date("2015-01-01"),length.out=100,by="day")))
my_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(date)) +
  geom_density()
my_plot
```

[image: ok]

This looks as expected. But as soon as I define a sexond axis the format of the first changes:

```
my_plot +
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . , name = "test", breaks = NULL, labels = NULL))
```

[image: wrong]

In this example the second axis could be replaced with `labs(title= "test")`. It is just a minimal reproducible example. No matter how we define the second axis the first x axis does not show month anymore but numbers instead. How can I define a second axis without changing the format of the first?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You are not defining a _first_ axis anywhere in your example, let alone a second axis. Do you mean if you run `my_plot + labs(title= "test")` the axis labels change? If so, I can't reproduce the error. If you mean something else, can you be more specific, and show the exact code that replicates the problem? Thanks.

Comment: @AllanCameron I updated the question. Forgot to include `my_plot +
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . , name = "test", breaks = NULL, labels = NULL))`. I do need a second axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the second axis that causes the problem, it's that you are specifying `scale_x_continuous` instead of `scale_x_date`:

```r
my_plot +
  scale_x_date(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . , name = "test", breaks = NULL, labels = NULL))
```

[image]